# Ubuntu 12.04 for Vmware esxi 5.1

Tags: vmware

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 on a vpsphere ESXI 5.1 box. The install get's about half way and then crashes. Wondering if  Ubuntu has support for a Xeon E3-1245 Ivy bridge processor.

Answer (score 0):

Since the install get's started then the processor is not a problem. It's more likely a hardware issue which can be resolved by using the options under F6 before the install starts. Describe what happens when the install breaks so that we can give you better guidence.

Comment: Martyn, Thanks for the response. I've also tried to install 13.04 with the same result. I installed Ubuntu server and it went through perfectly fine. The install basically crashes and states that it's either due to a faulty Disk, DVD or CD reader or heat. Yet i installed server without a problem. I also have a bunch of server 2008 DC's running on the same VM Host. I still don't know why both versions of Ubuntu desktop are failing with the same error message. thnx

Comment: Nice info, should get you better response, VM not my cup of tea.